# How to change the order of elements in an array using a given index

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a long list of tuples in an array of size (264, 1, 3) which I want to reorder using a given index (for example, move elements 30:44 to the bottom, move the first value to the 56th value, etc.) I tried to create an index that looks something like this:

```
idx = np.s_[np.s_[1:12], np.s_[14:25], np.s_[27:36], ...
```

which extends until I have placed all my elements where I want them. When I try to put my array along that index, I get an error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 38 were indexed
```

Does anyone know the best way in numpy to reorder my values the specific way I want them? By the way, I need them to be in an asarray because these are RGB values which I will be displaying using PIL.

I also tried creating an empty numpy array and appending my ranges of tuples, but that did not give me the right array type for displaying using Image.fromarray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nested `s_` produces a slicer to slice on 38 dimensions.

I think you rather want to combine the slices:

```
idx = np.r_[1:12,14:25,27:36]
```

Or:

```
idx = np.r_[np.s_[1:12], np.s_[14:25], np.s_[27:36]]
```